A problem occurred configuring project ':expo'
A problem occurred configuring project ':expo'.
Could not get unknown property 'release' for SoftwareComponent container of type org.gradle.api.internal.component.DefaultSoftwareComponentContainer.
This error getting while running the command ./gradlew clean, This is a react native expo project.
the Java version is "20.0.2" and gradle version is 8.3.
I tried java versions 11,17,22, Still getting the error.
In my build.gradle file
signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            shrinkResources (findProperty('android.enableShrinkResourcesInReleaseBuilds')?.toBoolean() ?: false)
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }


Maybe it has to do with your keystore? Are you using eas build?

Try to run expo doctor and follow its advices.
